# Ubuntu 17.10 ignores xorg.conf

Tags: 17.10, xorg.conf

I switched to Ubuntu 17.10 from 17.04, where the same xorg.conf worked in /etc/xorg.conf, and Ubuntu seems to ignore the file. My workaround is the same as before in Ubuntu 17.04, I copied xorg.conf to /etc. But it wasn't loaded. I use the xorg.conf to set the right resolution and the driver. The xorg.conf would load the radeon driver and `lshw -c video` said that this driver is already loaded. I tried other locations for xorg.conf like the manpage sugguest without luck.

I hope someone of you can help me.

Comment: Are you in a Wayland session?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

17.10 uses wayland by default instead of x11.

On the login screen, you should have an option to selet an X11 session instead of the wayland session